# TYPO3 6.2 beta3 installation complaining about links

Tags: php, apache, installation, typo3

I am following the TYPO3 6.2 beta 3 install instructions at https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/INSTALL.md however in the first step of the installation the install tool complains (all are errors):

```
Path /index.php is not a link
The target /index.php should be a link, but is of type file. This can not be fixed. Please investigate.

Path /typo3 is not a link
The target /typo3 should be a link, but is of type dir. This can not be fixed. Please investigate.  

/typo3_src should be a link, but it does not exist
Links can not be fixed by this system 

PHP OpenSSL extension not working
Something went wrong while trying to create a new private key for testing. Please check the integration of the PHP OpenSSL extension and if it is installed correctly.
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
htdocs
  typo3
    .htaccess
    index.php -> ./typo3_src/index.php
    typo3 -> ./typo3_src/typo3/
    typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-6.2.0-beta3/
  typo3_src-6.2.0-beta3
```

I run the installation via accessing host/typo3/. It seems the links should be okay, why the error messages in the install tool?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error on an linux machine, where it was an different if a link has been created via

```
ln -s typo3 typo3 
# or
ln -s typo3/ typo3/
```

I was able to "fix" it, with the "correct" syntax. I guess ln -s typo3 typo3 was it, but i am sorry, i do not remember. I do not know, if there is a real difference, but i guess it just has been implemented to check for an special syntax and it has been overlocked, that another syntax could be fine to. On the otherhand it can be, that at some point the systems expects the path in an defined syntax

Comment: It does not let me use the second syntax saying: no such file or directory (during link creation). It seems it would just create the link in the ./typo3/ directory (which does not exist). I have also already tried the first syntax.